# Apache vhosts Error 403

Tags: apache, xampp, http-status-code-403, vhosts

Hello I am using Apache 2.4 with XAMPP on Windows 10. I've now searched trough a couple of Posts about vhosts but no one helped me...

So here's my vhosts:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# [...]

# Eigentliche VHost Konfiguration
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # DNS Name auf den der VHost hören soll
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Desktop/bbcmvc/public"
    ServerName phototable.local    

    # Nochmals
    <Directory "C:/Users/Desktop/bbcmvc/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Options +Includes
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What's wrong? If I open the browser and go to `phototable.local` it always says:

> Access denied! Error 403

Comment: Check Is there any `.htaccess` file in `C:/Users/Desktop/bbcmvc/public` ?

Comment: @SahilGulati Thank you for your answer but I found the error the path was just wrong after `Users` I should maybe specify a user (`C:/Users/WasteD/Desktop/bbcmvc....`)